# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
@staticmethod
def get_level(score):
    e = 0

    for i in range(1000):
        score -= e * 1.2 + 100

        if score <= 0:
            return i, -score

    return 1000, -1

level = self.get_level(p.wins * 10)

if level < 5:
return
```

Как правильно задать проверку?(

Comment: а что именно надо проверить? возвращается пара значений, а не одно, с каким из чисел в итоге надо сравнить?

Comment: Мне нужно сравнить уровень игрока, я сейчас подумал, if round(level) < 5:
Так будет правильно?

Comment: level — это кортеж, его нельзя сравнивать с числом. Определитесь, какое из двух чисел кортежа вам нужно, и допишите `[0]` или `[1]` соответственно

Comment: Ты возвращаешь **два** числа. Например 1000 и -1. Какое из них ты хочешь сравнить с 5?

Comment: 1000, Вроде бы понял, извините за глупый вопрос, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае функция `get_level` возвращает [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple), а не одно конкретное число.

Так как возвращается два значения, а сравнить нужно только одно, нужно указать какое конкретно.

Сделать это можно с помощью индекса:

```
level = self.get_level(p.wins * 10)

if level[0] < 5:
```

Либо с помощью распаковки tuple:

```
level, score = self.get_level(p.wins * 10)

if level < 5:
```

Comment: Спасибо большое